# How to store a long vector in text file?

Tags: r

For each item, I have an sparse vector including 5000 variables, should I store it in kind of json format like:

```
1:3,40:2,500:3
```

or just in a vector format:

```
1,0,0,0.....3.......
```

If in the first format, hoe can R read it as a vector?

EDIT:

Right now I have tried the second approach and the file size increases exponentially. So maybe other ways should be used instead.

Comment: You can store it the first way, use readLines() to read it, parse through strsplit() or some such thing and reconstruct your full vector in memory.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more efficient way to 'un extract' it, but here is one way that gets you to recover the vector back:

```
s <- readLines('filename')
s
[1] "1:3,40:2,500:3"

valList <- unlist(strsplit(s, ','))
valList <- sapply(unlist(valList), function(x) strsplit(x, ':'))
as.numeric(unlist(sapply(valList, function(x) {x <- as.numeric(x); rep(x[1], x[2])})))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Indeed my data file also contains another columns and there are more than 90,000 rows. I tried to apply your method after reading the whole data but failed. Could you please give me more details?